# Apply-Templates Issue with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to set up an XSLT to translate an XML with two nodes with multiple elements in each node and I'm running into an issue when using templates. I'm new to templates, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

I've tried mutiple different templates and even included the elements from Extended Fields inside the common node since I'm not sure it's an issue with there being two separate nodes. The output, when I do get output in the  element, is all of the values from Extended Fields. So, any help would be appreciated!

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:k="urn:tradefeed-xsd"
xmlns:ns0="http://OpenGeneva"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dm="urn:DataMapping"
>

     <xsl:template match="k:Field[@calcrt='DS122'][. = 'Mtge']">
      <xsl:value-of select="k:TradeAmount"/>
    </xsl:template>


  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:Root>
    
<xsl:for-each select="//k:BatchFeed/k:TradeFeed/k:Common">


<Transaction>

    <OriginalFace><xsl:apply-templates select="//k:Common"/></OriginalFace>
        <Investment><xsl:value-of select="k:BloombergGlobalIdentifier"/></Investment>

</Transaction>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ns0:Root>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BatchFeed xmlns="urn:tradefeed-xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<TradeFeed>
        <Common>
            <TradeAmount>2000000.0</TradeAmount>
            <BloombergGlobalIdentifier>BBG01412S0N8</BloombergGlobalIdentifier>
        </Common>
        <ExtendedFields>
            <Field calcrt="DS122" name="MARKET_SECTOR_DES">Mtge</Field>
        </ExtendedFields>
    </TradeFeed>
</BatchFeed>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Root xmlns:dm="urn:DataMapping" xmlns:k="urn:tradefeed-xsd" xmlns:ns0="http://OpenGeneva">
   <Transaction>
      <OriginalFace>2000000.0</OriginalFace>
      <Investment>BBG01412S0N8</Investment>
   </Transaction>
</ns0:Root>
```

Comment: It is hard to tell what you want to achieve if there is a single `Common` element in the input sample but the `<xsl:for-each select="//k:BatchFeed/k:TradeFeed/k:Common">` suggests there is more than one. Also, if you want a result `Transaction` element, do you need that for each `Common` in the input or perhas rather for each `TradeFeed`? That sounds like the parent you would want with a template to `Transaction` and then make sure the relevant children are processed in the right order/position.

Comment: Yes, there will be multiple TradeFeeds, each with a common and extended fields node.

Comment: It is not clear what you want the `<xsl:template match="k:Field[@calcrt='DS122'][. = 'Mtge']">` for as the content of that element doesn't seem to have any data you have in your expected output.

Comment: I could very well be thinking about templates wrong. My idea is that if the template encounters the field with DS122 and Mtge in its value, that it will export the TradeAmount to the original face field.

Comment: The `OriginalFace` element in your expected output seems to be populated from the `TradeAmount` element so it seems you need/want a template mapping that element to the OriginalFace element.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:k="urn:tradefeed-xsd">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
<xsl:template match="/k:BatchFeed">
    <ns0:Root xmlns:dm="urn:DataMapping" xmlns:k="urn:tradefeed-xsd" xmlns:ns0="http://OpenGeneva">
        <xsl:for-each select="k:TradeFeed/k:Common">
            <Transaction>
                <OriginalFace>
                    <xsl:value-of select="k:TradeAmount"/>
                </OriginalFace>
                <Investment>
                    <xsl:value-of select="k:BloombergGlobalIdentifier"/>
                </Investment>
            </Transaction>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ns0:Root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 2 or 3 and template matching the wanted output (I didn't bother to include unused namespaces) can be achieved with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xpath-default-namespace="urn:tradefeed-xsd"
  xmlns:ns0="http://OpenGeneva"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/BatchFeed">
    <ns0:Root>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ns0:Root>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="TradeFeed">
    <Transaction>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Common"/>
    </Transaction>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="TradeAmount">
    <OriginalFace>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </OriginalFace>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="BloombergGlobalIdentifier">
    <Investment>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Investment>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to output the data I needed by changing the scope of <xsl:for-each select="//k:BatchFeed/k:TradeFeed/k:Common"> to <xsl:for-each select="//k:BatchFeed/k:TradeFeed">.